# Change existing value in elements with conditon using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Im Trying to copy all the elements and change AdmissionNo of selected students using xslt

input XML is like :

```
<College Name="" RoadNo="" BlockNo="" City="" >
<Students>
<Student Name="ABC" AdmissionNo="123" />
<Student Name="CDE" AdmissionNo="456" />
<Student Name="EFG" AdmissionNo="678" />
<Student Name="GHI" AdmissionNo="980" />
<Student Name="IJK" AdmissionNo="767" />
</Students>
</College>`your text`
```

change AdmissionNo of students with Name CDE & GHI to 989 & 765 respectively

Tried below xsl which gives copies complete xml

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java" exclude-result-         prefixes="java" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
     <College>
         <xsl:copy-of select="College/@*"/>
         <Students>
             <xsl:copy-of select="College/Students/*[local-name()='Student']"/>
         </Students>
     </College>
 </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected result:

```
<College Name="" RoadNo="" BlockNo="" City="" >
<Students>
<Student Name="ABC" AdmissionNo="123" />
<Student Name="CDE" AdmissionNo="989" />
<Student Name="EFG" AdmissionNo="678" />
<Student Name="GHI" AdmissionNo="765" />
<Student Name="IJK" AdmissionNo="767" />
</Students>
</College>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to implement the condition?

Comment: If you copy the Student elements, then you cannot modify them. You should use the identity transform template as your basis, then add templates for the Student elements (or AdmissionNo attributes) that you want to change.

Comment: Your stylesheet does nothing that is even remotely relevant to the problem you state. This looks like an attempt to get someone to write your code for you.

Comment: Tried below xsl which is working as expected,but is there any other optimal way to do this? 
<xsl:stylesheet >
<xsl:template match="/">
<College>
<xsl:copy-of select="College/@*"/>
<Students>
<xsl:copy-of select="College/Students/Student[@Name!='CDE' and @Name!='GHI']"/>
<Student>
<xsl:attribute name="Name">
 <xsl:value-of select="'CDE'"/>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="AdmissionNo">
 <xsl:value-of select="'989'"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</Student>
</Students>
</College>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. Add this to your question. -- P.S. I don't think that's "working as expected". I suggest you heed the advice given by @y.arazim.